# How do you perform queries without specifying shard key in mongodbapi and how do you query across partitions?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

How do you perform queries without specifying shard key in `mongodb api` and how do you query across partitions?

In sql api the latter is enabled by setting `EnableCrossPartitionQuery` to `true` on the request but I'm not able to find anything like that for the `mongodb api`. And my queries that work on an `unsharded` collection now fails(queries that specify the shard key works as expected).

The queries fail indiscriminately of whether I use the `AsQueryable` extension syntax or the aggregation framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was confirmed a bug by the Product Group team! Will be fixed in first two weeks of september in case anyone runs into the same problems in the mean time.

Answer (score 2):

As I know, no such property similar to `EnableCrossPartitionQuery` in CosmosDB Mongo API. In fact, CosmosDB is an independent server implementation that does not directly align with MongoDB server versions and features.

CosmosDB supports a subset of the MongoDB API and translates requests into the CosmosDB SQL equivalent. CosmosDB has some different behaviours and results, particularly with their implementation of partitioning as compared to MongoDB's sharding. But the onus is on CosmosDB to improve their emulation of MongoDB.

Certainly, you could add feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db) to get official assistance or consider using [MongoDB Atlas](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/microsoft-azure/) on Azure if you'd like full MongoDB feature support.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you, we choose MongoDb on Azure consciously over Atlas because Cosmos combines the best of both worlds(automatic indexing being one but perhaps most importantly the massive cheap scalability). Cosmos goes far in promising things; planet-scale, multi-api, etc it's almost on every page of it's azure documentation. It also boasts "Compatible with existing MongoDB libraries, drivers, tools, and applications." We believe that in order to be both multi-api and planet-scale all API's should support collections that are more than 20GB and can run on more than one instance(shard).

Comment: We have contacted azure support and the support engineers agreed that this is not an optional feature. They've escalated the issue to the product team and I'll keep posting to this thread until it's resolved(for anyone who comes here after me).

Comment: @Kdog Sure, waiting for your any progress related to this issue.

Comment: @Kdog Hi,Kdog.If you get any updates, you could post it here and I'll set them into my answer for others' reference so that you could mark the answer.Thanks.